# Select length(col) to get BLOB content size in jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

The following SQL works

```
CREATE TABLE stored_file (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  content BLOB,
  content_length LONG,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


UPDATE stored_file SET content_length = length(content)
```

But I can't do the same in jOOQ.

```
getContext().update(STORED_FILE)
  .set(STORED_FILE.CONTENT_LENGTH, DSL.length(STORED_FILE.CONTENT))
```

DSL.length only allows a String field type.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you hit jOOQ's limits, resort to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). You can write your own length function like this:

```
class MyDSL {
    public static Field<Long> length(Field<byte[]> field) {
        return DSL.field("length({0})", Long.class, field);
    }
}
```

And now use that in all your statements:

```
getContext().update(STORED_FILE)
            .set(STORED_FILE.CONTENT_LENGTH, MyDSL.length(STORED_FILE.CONTENT))
```

Of course, if you really want to keep the length of a blob in sync with the blob itself, you're probably better off [using a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) (I'm assuming MySQL), or perhaps a view.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to stay database-agnostic for the moment due to an impending H2 -> Postgres migration.

Answer (score 0):

your code DSL.length(STORED_FILE.CONTENT) is generated exception because here allowed string but you are using BLOB data type so u changed your data type of the column content....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that only String is allowed, that's why I want to know how to do it with BLOB / byte[].

Comment: You really shouldn't change the data type of a database column just because some upstream framework doesn't support a simple function on that column...